# Xcode crashes on open

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Xcode 5 gave me no problems, but I ever since I updated to Xcode 6, Xcode won't open, and the following error report comes up:

```
Process:         Xcode [1469]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 712682811
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [155]
Responsible:     Xcode [1469]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-26 20:51:50.508 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  4882CC3E-8FD9-CE38-ABC5-48E777B6C1A3

Sleep/Wake UUID: A4E97A0E-05A1-4502-8A9C-D16C8D0473F3

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-6245/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/Foundation/Specifications/XCSpecification.m:835
Details:  name should be a string, but it is nil
Object:   <XCCompilerSpecification: 0x7fb756f66200>
Method:   -initAsMissingSpecificationProxyWithIdentifier:name:description:inDomain:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb753c17430>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
```

along with a lot of backtrace info. I already tried deleting the contents of my DerivedData directory like another post has suggested, but it still crashes every time

Comment: as an experiment, try creating another user on your Macintosh and see if Xcode launches for that new user.

Comment: Have you change the Xcode name in Application folder? If you changed it then pls try after revert its name.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I tried launching it from the guest user on the same laptop, and it works perfectly. So it's a problem with my own file system? I didn't change anything between when I was using Xcode 5 and when I updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this same problem. Clearing Xcode's user settings fixed it for me:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```